# How do I enable an input after selecting an option?

Tags: javascript, html

How do I enable an input after selecting an option? I want to enable the input of "campoOne" after selecting an option of "campoZero".

```
    <div id="one">
    <table> 
    <tr>
    <td class="honeydew">Produt</td>
    <td class="honeydew"><select type="text" name="campoZero" class="honeydew" id="campoZero">
    <option disabled selected>Select</option>  
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <var id="valorZero"></var>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
    <td class="gray">Boxes</td>
    <td class="gray"><input disabled onchange="somaTudo()" type="text" name="campoOne" class="gray" id="campoOne" maxlength="3" value="">
    <var id="valorOne"></var>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("campoOne").disabled = false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JavaScript` to do that, So you can add an event listener to the "campoZero" change event, In the example below, I check if the value of "campoZero" is equal to "1". If it is, I enable the "campoOne" input by setting its disabled property to false:

```js
var campoZero = document.getElementById("campoZero");
  var campoOne = document.getElementById("campoOne");

  campoZero.addEventListener("change", function() {
    if (campoZero.value == "1") {
      campoOne.disabled = false;
    } else {
      campoOne.disabled = true;
      campoOne.value = ""; // Reset the value of campoOne when it is disabled
    }
  });
```

```html
<div id="one">
    <table> 
    <tr>
    <td class="honeydew">Produt</td>
    <td class="honeydew"><select type="text" name="campoZero" class="honeydew" id="campoZero">
    <option disabled selected>Select</option>  
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <var id="valorZero"></var>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
    <td class="gray">Boxes</td>
    <td class="gray"><input disabled onchange="somaTudo()" type="text" name="campoOne" class="gray" id="campoOne" maxlength="3" value="">
    <var id="valorOne"></var>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
```